# How to use multithreading / multiprocessing in place of For loop with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

Currently, I am in a project in which performing validation based on the data provided in the row dataframe, so my current approach is a sequential approach to perform validation.

```
for index in mt.index():
    #File Reading 
    #performing validation
```

But I want to implement multithreading/Multiprocessing to enhance my processing time in the current approach it will take more time than expected.
Can anyone suggest or help me to how to implement multithreading/multiprocessing which enhances my Script performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pool API:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool()

def validate(index):
   ## do validation work for a given index here

result = p.map(validate, mt.index())
```

The map function will parallelize the loop over the values of `mt.index()`. Check out [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) for more options.

Comment: is it possible to pass multiple arguments to the validate function .

Comment: yes, you can pass a tuple `map(validate, mt.index(), args=(tuple of arguments)`